# How to pass file to the program from the command line

Tags: c#

I am writing a wpf application which should draw lines due points given in a file.

How can I pass a file in the command line to my c# program?
For example something like

```
MyProgram.exe < file.txt
```

In addition how can I do this in visual studio for debugging?
I know I can set command line args and can read them with

```
var args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do is call the program in this way, "filedetails.exe myfile.txt"

Example :

```
C:\Users\FILEREADER>filedetails.exe myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass a file in the command line to my c# program? For example > something like
>
> `MyProgram.exe <file.txt`

You can try this [Console.OpenStandardInput()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx55zca2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to pass file content as a parameter. You currently pass file content correctly:

```
MyProgram.exe < file.txt
```

all you need is to read it, I put a small cmd application:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
```

In wpf application:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var result = "";
        string line;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            result += (line);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
```

[Check here](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) for more information about about command line redirections.